# handle buttonEvent for UITableViewCell?

Tags: events, uitableview, uibutton

i have a custom TableViewCell with one button and One uilabel. actually where do mi handle this download event and how?[image]

this is my custom cell. i tried to handle like this but got the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [downloadPageCell downloadSong:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94b1490'
*** First throw call stack:
```

my code is here

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  downloadPageCell *newCell = nil;

  newCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

   if(newCell == nil)
   {
     NSLog(@"newCell ===================");
     NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"downloadPageCell" owner:self options:nil];
     newCell  = [ nibViews lastObject];
  }

  newCell.titleText.text=[URLTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [newCell.downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(DOWNLOAD:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

return newCell;
}
```

what is the real code for handling button event from cell?

**edits**

```
   -(void)downloadButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
 {
   NSLog(@"download button pressed");

 }
```

Comment: button action works now, i changed the selector method to       -(void)downloadButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"download button pressed");
   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign tag to each and every button by

```
newCell.downloadButton.tag=cell.indexPath.row
```

& in action u can find which button has been pressed by button tag and give different action to all the button.
You can use below method to find button.

```
UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

if(btn1.tag==1) {
  // call action for that first cell button
}
```

and so on.

Comment: but i have the same action for all buttons, but only changes the url

Comment: but this action is not working, is their any problem with this code? [newCell.downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: @NeerajNeeru where is your selector method i.e. in which class

Comment: see my edit, nothing i just slogged to check whether it is working or not